# JavaScript/jQuery | Open link in new tab while remaining focus (mimic ctrl/cmd click)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically, I want to be able to open links (using key commands not the mouse) in new tabs while remaining focus on the current window.

The only example I've seen of this being done is like so...

```
window.open("http://mysite.com/thing.php?id=" + thingid, '_blank');
self.focus();
```

However this method is sloppy because it will momentarily focus the new window and then jump back to the original window. I don't want it to ever leave the open window.

So, does anyone know how this task can be accomplished in JavaScript/jQuery? Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You'll never get past popup blockers.

Comment: Well I hope you're not right about that... This would be an excellent option for users to be able to navigate through posts, then open interesting ones in new tabs to come back to later without hindering navigation.

Comment: This would be an excellent option for ads with their irritating pop-ups.

Comment: True... but ads are still extremely annoying in the manner in which they do them (just popping up and stealing focus). So I don't know how much I agree with the decision to hinder website functionality when they have a significantly more annoying option for advertisements anyway.

Comment: If i got your question right then you want something like this: myWindow = window.open("http://mysite.com/thing.php?id=" + thingid, '_blank'); myWindow.focus();

Comment: did you solved how? i have the same need.

Comment: Well I did solve it, but my solution may be specific to my situation. Essentially what I did is I created an anchor tag with _blank with the same dimensions as the item they're clicking. I put this anchor tag in the background then when they click ctrl/cmd it pops up in front. I disable it from popping up front on ctrl/cmd if they're hovering over an item which is meant to disable it. There was a bit more to it than that because it would be problematic if they were trying to click a link in the item and not the item itself but clicked command to early but the anchor was blocking it though.